# forbid saving as in a given folder using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a folder containing many .xls and .xlsm sheets, this folder will be distributed to many people in the company, in order not to alter the integrity of the sheets in the folder I want to disable saving any files in this folder, all filles saved will have to be "saved as" in a location different than the folder called project.Here is what have found so far.

Cheers

```
  Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     '  Following line will prevent all saving
    Cancel = True
     '  Following line displays the Save As Dialog box
    If SaveAsUI Then SaveAsUI = True
     ' How do I forbid the folders path ???
  End Sub
```

Comment: so what should I do to disable saving in the folder?

Comment: Excel doesn't support such a feature to prevent saving in a directory. It's the windows folders Security settings that would prevent from saving it in that folder. This question isn't really a good fit for SO, try SuperUser.

Comment: but long-story short you can right-click the folder, go to Security tab chose `SYSTEM` as the group then click `Edit` and **deny** access for *writing*

Comment: Thanks mehow! would denying access forbid any user to save in the folder?

Comment: @user2453446: Is the path to the folder a static one?

Comment: @SiddharthRout what about the bug that shows the dialogbox twice :/

Comment: the folder will be distributed on a USB key then its hard to say if it is going to be copied on the computer or and called from its new location or from the key.

Comment: @user2453446: One could use the `Thisworkbook.Path` to check for the path? i.e if the user doesn't move the file out of the folder

Comment: @mehow: You use boolean variables to tackle that :)

Comment: @mehow I just tried denying writing access and it did not work.@SiddharthRout I am a bit confused by your method involving the boolean and the Thisworkbook.Path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with one way of doing it. Maybe someone can give you a better answer.

It will save  a file to your default location which is set to be `C:\MyFiles` and show a MessageBox after with the path to the file.

Only use this code if you do not want to ask the user where to save the file and save it in a static location then notify him/her of the location the file was saved to.

The below code goes in here (ThisWorkbook Object Module)

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
    Else

        Dim path As String
        path = "C:\MyFiles\"

        If Len(dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
           MkDir path
        End If

        Me.SaveAs Filename:=path & Me.Name, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

        MsgBox "This file has been saved in " & path & Me.Name
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

## update!

If all your users are on Windows 7 than you can change the path to

```
path = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\"
```

This will go to each user's desktop regardless of their username. The `Environ$("username")` function returns currently logged in username.

Comment: This is great! it works perfectly thank you so much mehow. on second thought I believe that the user would like to save the file on its desktop ( as some of them are not familiar with excel and computers). I tried changing the path to 'code'"C:\User\Desktop\"'code' but the exact adress requires the name of the user e.g 'code'"C:\Users\james\Desktop"'code'which will always change, is there a way to avoid save on the desktop for any user?

Comment: thank you for your precious help, but i'm still experimenting issues, the code works ... some times other times it displays the msgbox but does not always save it. If I remove the second 'code' cancel=true 'code' it will save the document on the desk top but excel will crash.

Comment: are you saving with `Save` or `SaveAs` ?

Comment: I 'm saving with the save icon from the macro interphase but the user would not be able to access it and would probably use the save shortcut from the excel interphase.

Comment: @user2453446 I honestly dont know how to help you further :/ Post another question with the code you currently have and explain that the Excel is crashing, and maybe ask why? Maybe there are people who can help you but i am no further help in this case.

Comment: Events should be disabled as saving will re-call the sub.

Answer (score 0):

This version saves to the User Desktop regardless of the Windows O/S version

It also disables `Events` so that the code doesn't call itself recursively.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If ThisWorkbook.Saved Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ws.specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name & " saved to " & ws.specialfolders("Desktop")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    MsgBox "workbook has not been saved before", vbCritical
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```